# Which functions are called 'under the hood' when using Ecto.Repo in elixir

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to get a better understanding of Ecto adapters in elixir. I have begun trying to build my own adapter using [`Ecto.Adapters.Postgres`](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto_sql/blob/master/lib/ecto/adapters/postgres.ex) as a base. This seemed like a good choice to start with as it is the default adapter used with Phoenix.

I can use my adapter in my own projects now by updating the the following line in my project's repo file...

```
defmodule UsingTestAdapter.Repo do
  use Ecto.Repo,
    otp_app: :using_test_adapter,
    adapter: TestAdapter  # <------ this line
end
```

At the moment it has the same functionality as the postgres adapter. I have been trying to edit some of the functions found in the [`Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.Connection`](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto_sql/blob/master/lib/ecto/adapters/postgres/connection.ex) and I have realised that they do not work quite how I expected.

The [`insert`](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto_sql/blob/master/lib/ecto/adapters/postgres/connection.ex#L151) function for example does not actually use the params passed into `Repo.insert`.

To make this a little more clear imagine we have the following table, `Comments`...

```
| id | comment |
| -- | ------- |
```

Now `Repo.insert(%Comments{comment: "hi"})` is called.

I want to modify the adapter, so that it ignores the "hi" value that is passed in and instead inserts a comment of "I am the adapter, and I control this database. Hahaha (evil laugh)"...

```
| id | comment                                                            |
| -- | ------------------------------------------------------------------ |
| 1  | I am the adapter and I control this database. Hahaha (evil laugh)" |
```

However, the `insert` function does not appear to actually take the data to be stored as an argument.

My initial thought of what happened with ecto adapters was that when a user calls one of the repo functions it called the corresponding function in the `Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.Connection` module. This does appear to happen but other steps seem to be happening before this.

If anyone has a better understanding of the chain of functions that are called when `Repo.insert` (and any other Repo function) is called, please explain below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had the time to look into this more deeply and feel that I now have a better understanding.

I'm going to list the steps, in order, that happen when a user calls `Repo.insert` in an elixir app.

### Step 1. Call Repo.insert

```
AppName.Repo.insert(%AppName.Comments{comment: "hi"})
```

### Step 2. AppName.Repo Module

```
defmodule AppName.Repo do
  use Ecto.Repo, otp_app: :app_name, adapter: adapter_name
end
```

> (This is the default set up for a phoenix application)
>
> The `use Ecto.Repo` allows for all the functions defined in that module to be used in the module that calls it. This means that when we call `AppName.Repo.insert`, it goes to our module, sees there is no function defined as insert, sees the `use` marco, checks that module, sees a function called `insert` and calls that function (this is not exactly how it works but I feel it explains it well enough).

### Step 3. Ecto.Repo Module

```
def insert(struct, opts \\ []) do
  Ecto.Repo.Schema.insert(__MODULE__, struct, opts)
end
```

[Where function is defined](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v3.0.7/lib/ecto/repo.ex#L189)

### Step 4. Ecto.Repo.Schema Module

#### 4.1

```
# if a changeset was passed in
def insert(name, %Changeset{} = changeset, opts) when is_list(opts) do
  do_insert(name, changeset, opts)
end

# if a struct was passed in
# This will be called in this example
def insert(name, %{__struct__: _} = struct, opts) when is_list(opts) do
  do_insert(name, Ecto.Changeset.change(struct), opts)
end
```

[Where function is defined](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/master/lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex#L204-L210)

This step ensures that the data that is passed to `do_insert` in the the form of a changeset.

#### 4.2

```
do_insert(name, Ecto.Changeset.change(struct), opts)
```

> Not pasting whole function as it is very long.
>   [Where function is defined](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/master/lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex#L212-L282)

This function does a fair amount of data manipulation and checks for errors. If all goes well it ends up calling the `apply` function

#### 4.3

```
defp apply(changeset, adapter, action, args) do
  case apply(adapter, action, args) do # <---- Kernel.apply/3
    {:ok, values} ->
      {:ok, values}
    {:invalid, _} = constraints ->
      constraints
    {:error, :stale} ->
      opts = List.last(args)

      case Keyword.fetch(opts, :stale_error_field) do
        {:ok, stale_error_field} when is_atom(stale_error_field) ->
          stale_message = Keyword.get(opts, :stale_error_message, "is stale")
          changeset = Changeset.add_error(changeset, stale_error_field, stale_message, [stale: true])

          {:error, changeset}

        _other ->
          raise Ecto.StaleEntryError, struct: changeset.data, action: action
      end
  end
end
```

[Where function is defined](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/master/lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex#L644-L670)

This `apply/4` function calls the [`Kernel.apply/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#apply/3) function with the `module`, `function name` and `arguments`. In our case the module is `AdapterName` and the function is `:insert`.

This is where our adapter comes into play :D (finally).

### Step 5. AdapterName

The `apply/3` function call above takes us to our created adapter.

```
defmodule AdapterName do
  # Inherit all behaviour from Ecto.Adapters.SQL
  use Ecto.Adapters.SQL, driver: :postgrex, migration_lock: "FOR UPDATE"
end
```

There is no insert function defined in this module but as it is '**using**' `Ecto.Adapters.SQL` let's look at this module next.

### Step 6. Ecto.Adapters.SQL Module

```
defmodule Ecto.Adapters.SQL do

...

      @conn __MODULE__.Connection

...

      @impl true
      def insert(adapter_meta, %{source: source, prefix: prefix}, params,
                 {kind, conflict_params, _} = on_conflict, returning, opts) do
        {fields, values} = :lists.unzip(params)
        sql = @conn.insert(prefix, source, fields, [fields], on_conflict, returning)
        Ecto.Adapters.SQL.struct(adapter_meta, @conn, sql, :insert, source, [], values ++ conflict_params, kind, returning, opts)
      end

...
end
```

`@conn` is defined as a [module attribute](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/module-attributes.html) and is just the [current calling module](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#__MODULE__/0) (**MODULE**) + .Connection.

The calling module, as discussed in point **5** is AdapterName

That means in the `insert` function, the following line...

```
@conn.insert(prefix, source, fields, [fields], on_conflict, returning)
```

is the same as

```
AdapterName.Connection.insert(prefix, source, fields, [fields], on_conflict, returning)
```

As our `adapter` is just the same as the [`postgres adapter`](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto_sql/blob/master/lib/ecto/adapters/postgres/connection.ex), it takes us to this next function.

### Step 7. AdapterName.Connection

```
def insert(prefix, table, header, rows, on_conflict, returning) do
  values =
    if header == [] do
      [" VALUES " | intersperse_map(rows, ?,, fn _ -> "(DEFAULT)" end)]
    else
      [?\s, ?(, intersperse_map(header, ?,, &quote_name/1), ") VALUES " | insert_all(rows, 1)]
    end

  ["INSERT INTO ", quote_table(prefix, table), insert_as(on_conflict),
   values, on_conflict(on_conflict, header) | returning(returning)]
end
```

[Where the function is defined](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto_sql/blob/master/lib/ecto/adapters/postgres/connection.ex#L151-L161)

To save some text in an answer that is already too long, I won't go into too much detail. This function doesn't actually take the params we passed into `Repo.insert` (way back in set one).

If we want to edit the params we need to do so in the `AdapterName` module. We need to define our own `insert` function so that it no longer calls the `insert` function defined in step 6.

### Step 8. AdapterName - Define our own insert.

For the sake of simplicity, we are going to just copy the `insert` defined in step 6 into our AdapterName module. Then we can modify that function to update params as we see fit.

If we do this we end up with a function like...

```
  def insert(adapter_meta, %{source: source, prefix: prefix}, params, on_conflict, returning, opts) do
    Keyword.replace!(params, :comment, "I am the adapter and I control this database. Hahaha (evil laugh)") # <---- changing the comment like we wanted :D

    {kind, conflict_params, _} = on_conflict
    {fields, values} = :lists.unzip(params)
    sql = @conn.insert(prefix, source, fields, [fields], on_conflict, returning)
    Ecto.Adapters.SQL.struct(adapter_meta, @conn, sql, :insert, source, [], values ++ conflict_params, kind, returning, opts)
  end
```

This now inserts a different value as we originally wanted.

Hopefully someone finds this helpful.